# Using the sleep function to tell the program to wait for 0.1 miliseconds on mac using C++

Tags: c++, sleep

Good afternoon,
I'm writing a program to print out an alphabetical snake and when I use the sleep() function that was from the <unistd.h> library to delay the snake movement but this function for me only worked when the waiting time was an integer or else if it was something like 0.1 it wouldn't work entirely. Is this a mac issue?
Does the sleep function only take integers?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int snake_speed = 1.5;
    int number = 0;
    string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char alphabet_num = alphabet[number];


    while(1 == 1){
        cout << "_____" << alphabet_num << endl;
        sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;
    cout << "____" << alphabet_num << "_" << endl;
    sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;
    cout << "___" << alphabet_num << "__" << endl;
    sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;
    cout << "__" << alphabet_num << "___" << endl;
    sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;
    cout << "_" << alphabet_num << "____" << endl;
    sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;
    cout << alphabet_num << "_____" << endl;
    sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;
    cout << "_" << alphabet_num << "____" << endl;
    sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;
    cout << "__" << alphabet_num << "___" << endl;
    sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;
    cout << "___" << alphabet_num << "__" << endl;
    sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;
    cout << "____" << alphabet_num << "_" << endl;
    sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;
    cout << "_____" << alphabet_num << endl;
    sleep(snake_speed);
    number += 1;

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html `unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);`

Comment: thanks you helped me achieve what I wanted! Thomas Sablik

Answer (score 0):

The [POSIX `sleep` function](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) is a non-portable way to sleep for an integral number of seconds.

C++ offers, since C++11, [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for), which aims to offer a finer granularity of sleep duration.

Answer (score -2):

> Is this a mac issue?

Yes, but it's also an issue of every pre-emptive, multi-tasking OS. Sleep relinquishes your thread and you ask the OS thread scheduler to give you back control after a while. There are many other threads trying to run on your CPU, thousands and thousands on a regular home PC, so you'll be lucky to get back control within a few milliseconds. [Windows XP can't even guarantee 15ms](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c4ecabc-60ec-4bd8-9f7e-4a0f81cde8f6/sleep-and-settimer-has-1516-ms-minimum?forum=vcgeneral) for example, though newer NT-based Windows systems can guarantee anywhere between half a millisecond to 1.5ms with the proper OS-wide settings.

Which is why you'll never see sleep being used in the first place. It's lazy, inefficient and imprecise, the three things any game designer can't afford to be. If you want to wait 0.1ms, you write a `while` loop and keep looping until it's time to stop by looking at the system clock. Preferably while also processing OS messages.